# Can a legendary creature use a legendary resistance to pass a concentration check?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, saving-throw, concentration

As I was looking through some legendary creatures, I had a thought. Most legendary creatures get three Legendary Resistances per day, which they can use to automatically succeed on a saving throw.

A Concentration check is technically a Constitution saving throw, so does that mean that a creature can use a Legendary Resistance to automatically pass a Concentration check, or is it not considered a saving throw?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Yes, it is a Constitution Saving Throw

> Taking damage. Whenever you take damage while
>   you are concentrating on a spell, you must make a
>   Constitution saving throw to maintain your concentration.
>   The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take,
>   whichever number is higher. If you take damage from
>   multiple sources, such as an arrow and a dragon's
>   breath, you make a separate saving throw for each
>   source of damage.

PHB p.203: Constitution, Taking damage

### Yes, Legendary Resistance Would Work

> Legendary Resistance (3/Day). If the demilich fails a saving
>   throw, it can choose to succeed instead.

MM p.48, Demilich stat block.

A legendary creature could use legendary resistance to succeed, if it had uses left and it wasn't saving it for something else.